# Error "Attempted to get a metric series by specifying 2 dimension(s), but this metric has 3 dimensions" with Get-Metric method of telemetry client

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, appinsights

```
  string source = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.logger.PStore[Constants.CurrentKey]) ? "NA" : this.logger.PStore[Constants.CurrentKey];
  string cId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.logger.Store[Constants.CId]) ? "NA" : this.logger.Store[Constants.CId];


public virtual void GetMetric(string metricId, double metricValue, string source = "", string cId = "")
    {
        Metric metric = this.TelemetryClient.GetMetric(metricId, "Source", "CorrelationId");
        metric.TrackValue(metricValue, source, cId);
    }
```

The above code I am using to log data in app insight.GetMetric has 2 dimensions along with a metricId and Track value has value along with dimension.

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.17.0.146

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, not even using the same exact version you do.

Comment: @PeterBons The version that I have used is 2.10.0..but somehow that shows up in logs..and are you able to see this in the azure app insights log?